# Fluid inline version of f:cObject with array in data

Tags: typo3, fluid

I try to form the following Fluid Viewhelper to a inline version:

`<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.infoBox" data="{pageUid: '{data.uid}', colPos: '7'}"/>`

I tried a lot of things but what I thought it should be:

```
{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: lib.infoBox, data: {pageUid: '{data.uid}', colPos: '7'})}
```

But unfortunately its not working. Whats the right line here?
 I need to put it into an f:if to check if its empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

```
{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.infoBox', data: '{pageUid: \'{data.uid}\', colPos: \'7\'}')}
```

Note: the quotes in the inner values of the data array must be escaped.

Comment: As I know you have to esacape the quotes in the inner values of your data array: `data: '{pageUid: \'{data.uid}\', colPos: \'7\'}'`. with the current values (object/array and integers) you don't need quotes: `data: '{pageUid: data.uid, colPos: 7}'`.